# Variable not declared, inside a if..else statement

Tags: go, global-variables

I'm just started learning go lang, and I am confused about declaring variables in go lang

for example I've declare `req`, `er` inside if...else statement.

```
if strings.EqualFold(r.Method, "GET") || strings.EqualFold(r.Method, "") {
    req, er := http.NewRequest(r.Method, r.Uri, b)
} else {
    req, er := http.NewRequest(r.Method, r.Uri, b)
}


if er != nil {
    // we couldn't parse the URL.
    return nil, &Error{Err: er}
}

// add headers to the request
req.Host = r.Host
req.Header.Add("User-Agent", r.UserAgent)
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", r.ContentType)
req.Header.Add("Accept", r.Accept)
if r.headers != nil {
    for _, header := range r.headers {
        req.Header.Add(header.name, header.value)
    }
}
```

But I've got error from terminal

```
./goreq.go:127: req declared and not used
./goreq.go:127: er declared and not used
./goreq.go:129: req declared and not used
./goreq.go:129: er declared and not used
```

seems like anything I declared inside If statement is not working... How can I solved it?

Comment: I don't know much about `go`, but it seems like if you declare `req` and `er` before the if statement and assign them inside the if statement, then the warnings (are they warnings or actually errors?) should go away.

Comment: In Go, it is idiomatic to name the error result `err` rather than `er`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Because variables are only defined in the scope in which they are declared:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := 1
    fmt.Println(a)
    {
        a := 2
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

[go play](http://play.golang.org/p/OnQRqt_J6L)

The difference between `=` and `:=` is that `=` is just assignment and `:=` is syntax for variable declaration and assigment

This:

```
a := 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
var a int
a = 1
```

What you probably want is:

```
var req *http.Request
var er error
if strings.EqualFold(r.Method, "GET") || strings.EqualFold(r.Method, "") {
    req, er = http.NewRequest(r.Method, r.Uri, b)
} else {
    req, er = http.NewRequest(r.Method, r.Uri, b)
}


if er != nil {
    // we couldn't parse the URL.
    return nil, &Error{Err: er}
}

// add headers to the request
req.Host = r.Host
req.Header.Add("User-Agent", r.UserAgent)
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", r.ContentType)
req.Header.Add("Accept", r.Accept)
if r.headers != nil {
    for _, header := range r.headers {
        req.Header.Add(header.name, header.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, so how could I pass the variable out the scope?

Comment: you dont have to pass anything, you just have to declare them at the right place

Comment: it is too stupid, i always need `if a,err:=xxx();err!=nil {return err} a.yyy()`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have declared the variables `req` and `er` inside the `if else` condition and are trying to use it outside the scope (the scope is just the `if` and `else` inside which they are declared).

You need to declare `er` and `req` outside the `if else`