# Go scope with conditional statements (if) issue

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and I'm struggling with scope (as [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481288/variable-not-declared-inside-a-if-else-statement)).

The code below generates:

```
./excel.go:24: err declared and not used
./excel.go:25: sheet declared and not used
```

***Why does this happen? I have declared both `err` and `sheet` in the parent scope, haven't I?***

Excel.go:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/tealeg/xlsx"
)

func main() {
    var file *xlsx.File
    var sheet *xlsx.Sheet
    var row *xlsx.Row
    var cell *xlsx.Cell
    var err error

    fileName := "MyXLSXFile.xlsx"

    if _, err := os.Stat(fileName); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        fmt.Printf("File does not exist so create one");
        file = xlsx.NewFile()
        sheet, err = file.AddSheet("Sheet1")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("File exists so open");
        file, err := xlsx.OpenFile(fileName) // <-- line 24
        sheet := file.Sheets[0] // <-- line 25
    }

    row = sheet.AddRow()

    cell = row.AddCell()
    cell.Value = "I am a cell!"
    cell = row.AddCell()
    cell.Value = "I am another cell!"

    err = file.Save(fileName)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("help")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `=` instead of `:=`:

```
    file, err = xlsx.OpenFile(fileName) // <-- line 24
    sheet = file.Sheets[0] // <-- line 25
```

Go allows re-declaring variables with the same name in nested blocks. `:=` declares a new variable. In your case both `err` and `sheet` are declared inside else block but are not used there.

Comment: Note that both `file` and `err` need to declared beforehand to use `=` in the if statement. If you declare `file` before the `if` and expect `if file, err := someFunc()` to use the `file` you declared before, it won't work (you'll get `file declared but not used` error) and if you do `if file, err = someFunc()` that won't work either because `err` is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** Use `=` for pure assignments. `:=` declares a new variable.

`sheet := file.Sheets[0]` declares a new variable within the scope of the `else` block (see the chapter ["Short variable declaration" from the language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)). This variable shadows the variable of the same name declared in the outer scope and will not exist in the outer scope ([see the documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)):

> The scope of a constant or variable identifier declared inside a function begins at the end of the ConstSpec or VarSpec (ShortVarDecl for short variable declarations) and ends at the end of the innermost containing block.

So the variable `sheet` in line 25 and the variable `sheet` in lines 12 and 28 are actually **two different variables** (with the first one declared in line 25 never being used after assignment).

Comment: Thank you for the link, I misunderstood the `=` and `:=` principle.